# on_member_join não funciona, discord.py

Tags: python

Eu estava desenvolvendo um bot e então resolvi criar uma funcionalidade que recebesse membros e mandasse uma curta mensagem em sua DM.

Fiz o seguinte código:

Instância da classe Client:

```
client = discord.Client()
```

Função `on_member_join`

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(
        f'Olá {member.name}, bem vindo ao server!'
    )
```

Porém o código não funcionou. Me certifiquei de que o argumento `guild_subscriptions` estava com valor `True` e estou na versão `1.5.1`.

O que pode ter ocorrido e como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Caue, boloque o restante do código que esta usando, como voce esta criando a variavel `client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar uma `DM` para o usuario você precisa primeiro criar um chat privado com o usuario e depois enviar uma mensagem para essa canal.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()  # cria um chat privado
    await member.dm_channel.send(  # envia a mensagem para o chat privado
        f'Olá {member.name}, bem vindo ao server!'
    )
```

Referencias:

- https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#welcoming-new-members
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member#discord.on_member_join

Comment: Olá, mesmo aplicando o que você falou, o código continuou não funcionando